# keypress, keyup or keydown only work on the first ring in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, keyup, onkeyup

in my project have a jQuery Mobile textarea called "topic" on one page

I have this script I am using to count the characters entered in the textarea, but this script just gives me a result on the first keystroke. the other does not.

```
$(document).delegate("#topicDialog", "pageinit", function() {
$("#topic").keyup(function(e) {
        var tam = $(this).length;

        if (tam <= 61700){
            $("#maxCarac").html(tam +" typed characters. The maximum allowed is 61700");
        } else {
            alert("You have reached the maximum text size.\nPlease break your text into more than one topic.");
            $("#topic").val($("#topic").substring(61700));
        }
    });
});
```

[example in action](http://jsfiddle.net/wgbn/zdEzk/)

What can be happening?

Comment: When you are doing `$(this).length` that means it will check the object length which is always 1. You have to do `$(this).val().length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line needs to be changed

```
var tam = $(this).val().length;
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zdEzk/2/)

Comment: thanks. a silly mistake, but that sometimes happens after a lot of typing =)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use val().length

check the  update fiddle here

```
$("#topic").keyup(function(e) {
        var tam = parseInt($(this).val().length);

        if (tam <= 61700){
            $("#maxCarac").html(tam +" typed characters. The maximum allowed is 61700");
        } else {
            alert("You have reached the maximum text size.\nPlease break your text into more than one topic.");
            $("#topic").val($("#topic").substring(61700));
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manishkumarshr/zdEzk/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving incorrectly the length of the user input. Use this:

```
var tam = $(this).val().length;
```

Here a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qv5J6/).